# .obj file conversion to OpenGL model header file - indices and f parameters?

Tags: opengl, header, object-files

The OpenGL model header file I'm working with contains definitions along the following:

`static const float modelVertices[NUM_OBJECT_VERTEX * 3] = {}`

`static const float modelTexCoords[NUM_OBJECT_VERTEX * 2] = {}`

`static const float modelNormals[NUM_OBJECT_VERTEX * 3] = {}`

`static const unsigned short modelIndices[NUM_OBJECT_INDEX] = {}`

Where there are a bunch of numbers (floats and integers, as fitting) separated by comma's inbetween the brackets.

It seems straight-forward to convert an .obj file's `v, vt, vn` to the above format. My .obj file also has a bunch of `f`'s which include triplets separated by `/`. *I'm not sure what these parameters are exactly...*

Which parameters do I need to convert to get the fourth - the modelIndices?

(I need to admit in advance that I am a newbie to OpenGL, so apologies if this seems too elementary!)

Answer (score 1):

Triplets are just a face definition.

If you have
f 1 2 3

This means you have a triangle that is made of vertex of indices 1 2 and 3.

If all entries are like that, that means you can directly fill your `modelIndices` with those indices, and draw them using `GL_TRIANGLES`.

Now if they are separated by `/` this means you have different mapping between vertices position and texture coordinates and/or normals.

This is something [OpenGL can't handle directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893911/different-size-of-buffers-for-vertex-and-texture-coordinates/3893961#3893961) and the way to go for you is to explode the texcoord and normal data into arrays of the same size than vertice position array.

To do this is trivial: here's pseudo code:

```
read face data (triplets)
for each triplet
   read vertex indice
   read texcoord and normal indices
   fetch texcoord @ texcoord indice from your vt array
   store texcoord @ vertex indice in your modelTexCoords array
   fetch normal @ normal indice from your vn array
   store normal @ vertex indice in your modelTexCoords array

   etc
```

See also wikipedia's doc, which explain well .obj format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obj

Comment: hmm, so you're saying that `texcoord` (for usage in `modelTexCoords`) is actually *repeated* in each `/`-triplet as `vertex index/texcoord/normal index`?

Comment: hmm, so basically `vn` is repeated in the normal index of `modelTexCoords` as well as in `modelNormals` ... also, in the case where you have f's with a bunch of `1/2/3`'s, the modelIndices is just the first element (1 in this case) of each f triplet?

Comment: yes that's right, modelIndices are just the first element of each f triplet. I don't understand what do you mean by 'vn is repeated in the normal index of modelTexCoords' though.

Comment: I had thought the `vn`'s from the obj mapped directly to the `modelNormals`, but it seems the `vn`'s are also duplicated again in the `modelTexCoords`

Comment: the other thing is each line of `v` and `vn` show triplets (separated by spaces), so do the index mapping refer to line numb

Comment: To reformulate the question, what is the size of `v`, `vt` and `vn`? If they differ from `v`, that means you don't have same mapping for `vt` and `vn` and that's problematic for the reasons I've enumerated in my answer. About your last comment, that's right. Index mapping refer to line number!